# Facebook privilages for getting messages from wall

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I created simple facebook app which asks user for user_about_me, user_activites and user_status privilages. Now I want to get all my wall posts, so I make a request and receive only some of my profile data, but without wall posts. I noticed that my access_token is different from the one I can get in documentation: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/.

What should I change?

Answer (score 1):

You need read_stream permission.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

```
read_stream  Provides access to all the posts in the user's News Feed and
             enables your application to perform searches against the user's
             News Feed
```